# Perl/Python Scripts Fail to Access Internet/Network through Web GUI

Tags: php, python, apache, perl, privileges

Another way I could ask this question is:

**How do I set pages served by Apache to have higher privileges?** This would be similar to me setting an Application Pool in IIS to use different credentials.

I have multiple Perl and Python scripts I am publishing through a web front end. The front end is intended to run any script I have in a database. With most of the scripts I have no issues... but anything that seems to utilize the network returns nothing. No error messages or failures reported. Running from CLI **as ROOT** works, run from WEB GUI **as www-data** calling same command fails.

I am lumping Python and Perl together in this question because the issue is the same leading me to believe it isn't a code issue, it is a permissions issue. Also why I am not including code, initially.

These are running on linux using Apache and PHP5. Python 2.7 and Perl5 I believe. Here are examples of apps I have that are failing:

1. Python - Connecting out to VirusTotal API
2. Perl - Connecting to Domains and Creating a Graph with GraphViz
3. Perl - Performing a Wake On LAN function on a local network segment.

Comment: Go to the document root and do a `su www-data`. Then try to run the scripts as user www-data. If this fails it is not a problem of apache but simply because UNIX permissions do not allow you to access the scripts or the perl/python binary.

Comment: When I try to su www-data I get "This account is currently not available."

Comment: This means that the account has not shell. See https://geekpeek.net/this-account-is-currently-not-available-login-problems/ for how to fix it temporarily for testing but I recommend to set it back afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

So after I posted this I looked into Handlers like I use for IIS. That led me down the path of SUEXEC and through everything I tried I couldn't get Apache to load it. Even made sure that I set the bits for SETUID and SETGID.

When I was researching that I ran across .htaccess files and how they can enable CGI scripts. I didn't want to put in .htaccess files so I just made sure the apache.conf was configured to allow CGI. That also did not help.

So finally while I was studying .htaccess they referred to ScriptAlias. I believe this is what solved my issue. I modified the ScriptAlias section in an apache configuration file to point to my directory containing the script. After some fussing with absolute directories and permissions for the script to read/write a file I got everything to work except it isn't going through the proxy set by environment http_proxy. That is a separate issue though so I think I am good to go on this issue. I will attempt the same solution on my perl LAMP.

Comment: This is the site that led me down the final path. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-suexec-in-apache-to-run-cgi-scripts-on-an-ubuntu-vps